# C# Copying BitmapData (GDI+)

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

I'm currently developing a game engine in C#, using GDI+. At the moment I'm trying to make the graphics engine render bitmaps faster by implementing a faster way to copying one bitmap, to another.

I have a method I made called `CopyBitmap` which takes in the bitmap you wish to copy from, the bitmap you wish to copy to, the destination rectangle (Which is where and how big you want to place to the copied image) and a source rectangle (which is the portion of the image you wish to copy).

However, I don't know how to set the position and size of the copied image.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the <see cref="BitmapData"/> from one <see cref="Bitmap"/> to another.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="from">The <see cref="Bitmap"/> you wish to copy from.</param>
    /// <param name="to">The <see cref="Bitmap"/> you wish to copy to.</param>
    /// <param name="destRect">The location and size of the copied image.</param>
    /// <param name="srcRect">The portion of the image you wish to copy.</param>
    public static void CopyBitmap(Bitmap from, Bitmap to, Rectangle destRect, Rectangle srcRect)
    {
        // The bitmap we're copying from needs to know the portion of the bitmap we wish to copy
        // so lets pass it the src rect, it is also read only.
        BitmapData fromData = from.LockBits(srcRect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

        // The bitmap we're copying to needs to know where the copied bitmap should be placed, and also how big it is
        // so lets pass it the dest rect, it is also write only
        BitmapData toData = to.LockBits(destRect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of data we're copying from
        int bytes = Math.Abs(fromData.Stride) * from.Height;

        // convert it to bytes
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

       // I imaginge here is where I should set the position and size of the image I wish to copy to it's destRect

        // Copy the values to the bitmap we're copying to
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, toData.Scan0, bytes);

        // unlock them both
        from.UnlockBits(fromData);
        to.UnlockBits(toData);
    }
```

I think it might be worth mentioning that I don't wish to the `graphics.DrawImage` method, as this is why I'm creating the method in the first place.

Comment: Side note, you will want to check that `destRect` and `srcRect` lie within the bounds of the respective images correctly

Comment: Thank you, I'll do this now. Obviously, id does this with a simple Rectangle.IntersectsWith check?

Comment: You'd do it how you wish, but yes that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made several assumptions to show you an example of how to do this and I have also used `unsafe` code to give you the maximum possibly performance.

Assumptions made:

1. Rectangles lie in the images correctly
2. The images `PixelFormat`s are `Format32bppPArgb` and so 4 bytes per pixel
3. `srcRect` and `dstRect` have the same width and height

<sup>All code is untested but looks correct</sup>

```
public static unsafe void CopyBitmap(Bitmap from, Bitmap to, Rectangle destRect, Rectangle srcRect)
{
    //Check rects line up appropriatley

    //You should get this and the PixelFormat's of the images properly
    //unless you can alsways assume the same format
    const int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;

    BitmapData fromData = from.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, from.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    try
    {
        BitmapData toData = to.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, to.Size), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        try
        {
            //For the purpose of this example I will assume that srcRect and destRect have the same width and height

            int xOffset = (destRect.X - srcRect.X) * BYTES_PER_PIXEL;
            int yOffset = destRect.Y - srcRect.Y;

            for (int hi = srcRect.Y, hc = srcRect.Bottom; hi < hc; ++hi)
            {
                byte* fromRow = (byte*)fromData.Scan0 + (hi * fromData.Stride);
                byte* toRow = (byte*)toData.Scan0 + ((hi + yOffset) * toData.Stride);

                for (int wi = (srcRect.X * BYTES_PER_PIXEL), wc = (srcRect.Right * BYTES_PER_PIXEL);
                        wi < wc; wi += BYTES_PER_PIXEL)
                {
                    //Adjust this if you have a different format

                    toRow[xOffset + wi] = fromRow[wi];
                    toRow[xOffset + wi + 1] = fromRow[wi + 1];
                    toRow[xOffset + wi + 2] = fromRow[wi + 2];
                    toRow[xOffset + wi + 3] = fromRow[wi + 3];
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            to.UnlockBits(fromData);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        from.UnlockBits(fromData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141633/discussion-between-thelethalcoder-and-mathew-odwyer).

Comment: @MathewO'Dwyer Just tried my code with an image with an alpha component and it worked correctly, so i can't reproduce your result of losing the alpha channel

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap contanst "GetPixel" and "SetPixel" functions. I think you can use it for copy FrombitMap data to ToBitmap data.

GetPixel return a Color and SetPixel is the same.

Please try it.

Comment: The BitmapData class doesn't contain a SetPixel or GetPixel method, only the Bitmap class does.

Comment: These methods are also incredibly slow, hence the OP wanting to use `LockBits`